# Doubt on 2NF decomposition

Tags: database-design, database-theory

I have read that 1NF, 2NF and 3NF decompositions are lossless and dependency-preserving.

Consider this example on a relation **R(A,B,C,D)** with functional dependencies set as **FD ={ AB->CD, A->C, BC->D}**

Here when we do 2NF decomposition we get **R1(A,C)** with **FD ={A->C}**  and **R2(A,B,D)** with **FD ={AB->D}**

The functional dependency **BC->D** is lost when we join but we know that 2NF is dependency preserving so why is it that we are unable to preserve the original FD?

Comment: What algorithm did you use to get to these R1 and R2? Also - and before that - how did you check if the original R is in 2NF or not?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ R is not in 2NF as prime attribute A is deriving non-prime attribute C, inorder to get it to 2NF I have decomposed R into R1 and R2

Comment: Ah yes, AB is the only superkey. And indeed, since we have A->C, R is not 2NF.

Comment: You should conclude that the method you used for decomposition to 2NF is not dependency preserving.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ what are your thoughts on this "Although you decomposed the table using the dependency that violates 2NF (A→C), the new tables are in BCNF, and decomposition to BCNF is not always dependency preserving."

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ I know that prime deriving non-prime is a problem so I make a new table for the dependency, I dont know this algorithm name nor do i know any other algorithm...if there is an algorithm that decomposes into 2NF with preserving dependencies?

Comment: I don't think BCNF is related to the issue. Look for different decomposition algorithms, (e.g. the "Synthesis" algorithm for decomposition to 3NF, that is dependency preserving).

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ soo can I say there exist a way to decompose into 1NF, 2NF and 3NF which preserve the functional dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

> I have read that 1NF, 2NF and 3NF decompositions are lossless and dependency-preserving.

You didn't read that in a competent reference, because it's wrong. What is correct is that every schema has some lossless and dependency-preserving decomposition(s) to 3NF and, since 3NF implies 2NF, 2NF.

That doesn't mean that every decomposition to 3NF or 2NF is lossless and dependency-preserving or that every lossless decomposition to 3NF or 2NF is dependency-preserving.

["1NF" has no agreed meaning.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40640962/3404097) (All involve replacing some table with parameterized structure by some table(s) with a column per parameter.) This affects notions of higher NFs that are defined in terms of a 1NF.